# Proving that a binomial coefficient involving a power of $2$ is even

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, polynomials

In the process of proving that the polynomial $x^{2^n} + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, I am getting stuck on proving an intermediate result:

*Denote $f(X)=X^{2^n}+1.$ By a linear change of variables we have
$$f(X+1)=(X+1)^{2^n}+1=X^{2^n}+\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}\binom{2^n}{k}X^{2^n-k}+2$$
We use the following result: for every prime number $p$ and all positive integers $n,k$, $1\leq k\leq p^n-1$, the number $\binom{p^n}{k}$ is divisible by $p$. 
Then we can apply Eisenstein's criterion to obtain that $f(X+1)$ is irreducible. So, $f(X)$ is irreducible too.*

How can I show the result (using elementary methods)?

Comment: @Micah Would you care to elaborate how this applies?

Comment: With respect, @Micah, Lucas’s Theorem is miles too advanced, if it does apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s really easy. Note that $(A+B+C)^2=A^2 + B^2 +(2AB + 2AC + 2BC + C^2)$. When $C$ is divisible by $2$, things get better, and
in particular $(A+ 1+2C)^2 =A^2+1+2Z$ for some $Z$. Now use induction on the exponent on your $2$.

For instance, $(A+1)^8 = (A^2+1+2Z)^4 = (A^4+1+2Z')^2=A^8 + 1 + 2Z''$.